# Black screen when trying to install something

Tags: crash, visual-artifacts

I was trying to install something from the command prompt and before I could even do *anything*, my screen just turned black and there is a green moving line on the left side of my screen.

[image: photo of screen]

Comment: Take a screenshot if possible, but if you cannot then take a picture.

Comment: What were you installing?  Can you give me the exact command you typed in?

Comment: sudo apt instal

Comment: thats as far i got before it did what it did

Comment: So you never executed the command?  Did you press enter after you typed that?

Comment: No, I did not click anything. It just did that.

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with what you were trying to install and most likely an hardware issue.

Comment: This appears to be a random crash.  Did you try to reboot?  It could very well fix it.